# Apple macbook, Microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to calculate that in cell C1, if taxable income is 0-18,200, tax is 0, if 18,201-37,00, tax is 19%, if 37,001-80,000 tax is 32.5%

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

In case you want the total Tax then deducted from the amount you can use nested IF in C1:

```
=IF(B1<18201,0,IF(B1<37001,(B1-18200)*19%,IF(B1<80000,3572+(B1-37000)*32.5%,17547)))
```

B1 is the amount
3572  =19%*(37000-18200)

13975 =32.5%*(80000-37000)
17547 =3572+13975